# How can I add the contents of a List to a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have created a SqliteConnection to my database and in that database I have a table:

```
var conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + db);

        // Set the structure of the database
        if (!exists)
        {
            var commands = new[] {
        "CREATE TABLE Phrases (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Keyword TEXT, Translation1 TEXT, Translation2 TEXT)"
        };
            conn.Open();
            conn.Open();
            foreach (var cmd in commands)
            {
                using (var c = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    c.CommandText = cmd;
                    c.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
```

What I would like to do is to insert the contents of a List into that table:

```
    List<Phrase>

    public partial class Phrase
    {
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
        public string Translation1 { get; set; }
        public string Translation2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone give me some advice or a suggestion on how I could get the data from the list and insert into the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [INSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) SQLite syntax and it requires command parameters in C#.

You can wrap connection and commands into `using` and `try/catch` statements.

```
string db = "MyDB.s3db";
List<Phrase> phraseList = new List<Phrase>()
{
    new Phrase() { Keyword = "start", Translation1="Hi!", Translation2="Привет!" },
    new Phrase() { Keyword = "end", Translation1="Bye!", Translation2="Пока!" },
};

try
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + db))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string createCmd =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Phrases (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Keyword TEXT, Translation1 TEXT, Translation2 TEXT)";
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(createCmd, conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string insertCmd =
            "INSERT INTO Phrases (Keyword, Translation1, Translation2) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        foreach (Phrase phrase in phraseList)
        {
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(insertCmd, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Keyword",phrase.Keyword);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Translation1", phrase.Translation1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Translation2", phrase.Translation2);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
}
```