# how to insert a List object to sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

This is my class which helps me to deserialize json get result from api

```
public class STOCKS
    {
        public class RootObject  
        {

            [PrimaryKey] 

            public int sto_RECno { get; set; }
            public int sto_RECid_RECno { get; set; 
         }

      }
```

and this is my json deserialize operation.

```
var content = await _client.GetStringAsync("http://webapi/somewhere/");
var StockLIST= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<STOCKS.RootObject>>(content);
```

and i want to insert this data to my sqlite

```
 conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection(); 
                    conn.CreateTable<STOCKS.RootObject>();
 conn.Insert(StockLIST);
```

but it fails.

i dont understand, where i m wrong.?
my Stocks class contains nearly 90 variables. so i m looking for a appropriate solution to do it.

should i convert the list to datatable or what?

thank you for your help.

Comment: To confirm: are you trying to insert a list object, or each item of a list separately?

Comment: I think this is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055925/how-can-i-add-the-contents-of-a-list-to-a-sqlite-database

Comment: @Sainath .  I have nearly 90 variables in my STOCKS class. Should i write all of them one by one?

Comment: @John  I m new at programming. 
I want to insert the list object to sqlite.

For example.
Mylist contains 16 records .
And i want to insert all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an SQLite guy, but assuming that conn.Insert(...) works for a single item, then you simply need to loop through each item in the list and insert it:

```
foreach (var StockItem in StockLIST)
{
    conn.Insert(StockItem);
}
```

Comment: thank you. it worked amazingly. i m slowly slowly getting the idea.
is there a way to learn how to work with this classes? @John

Comment: conn.InsertAll(StockLIST); 


also this code works great without foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, You can use following way to insert your Object to the database.

```
  List<Note> StockLIST = new List<Note>();
        StockLIST.Add(new Note() {Text="bbbb",Gender="fame",Date= DateTime.UtcNow });
        StockLIST.Add(new Note() { Text = "bbbb1", Gender = "fame", Date = DateTime.UtcNow });
        StockLIST.Add(new Note() { Text = "bbbb2", Gender = "fame", Date = DateTime.UtcNow });
        StockLIST.Add(new Note() { Text = "bbbb3", Gender = "fame", Date = DateTime.UtcNow });

        foreach (var item in StockLIST)
        {
            await App.Database.SaveNoteAsync(item);
        }
```

You should use `async/await` when you insert your data to database. Here is code about achieve the `SaveNoteAsync`

```
    public Task<int> SaveNoteAsync(Note note)
    {
        if (note.ID != 0)
        {
            return _database.UpdateAsync(note);
        }
        else
        {
            return _database.InsertAsync(note);
        }
    }
```

When we should sqlite in the xamarin, we will connect to the database in the App.xaml firstly.

```
  public partial class App : Application
{
    static NoteDatabase database;

    public static NoteDatabase Database
    {
        get
        {
            if (database == null)
            {
                database = new NoteDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Notes5.db3"));
            }
            return database;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

Here is my demo(achieve CURD).You can refer to it

https://github.com/851265601/MyNewDataBase

Comment: @Fk Bey Are there any update for this issue, If the reply is help, please do not forget to mark it as answer(click the right-top ✔), It will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: i solved the problem handling each list item with foreach loop ( John )

and @Leon Lu   thank you for your codes. it works great.